# Get list of USB devices connected currently and their dev file in BASH

Tags: bash, unix, usb

What is the bash command for detecting all currently connected USB devices and getting the /dev/tty... file that corresponds to the USB device.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Give `lsusb` a try; for the corresponding file I plug in the device and use `dmesg`, but there sure is a better way...

Comment: Could you explain how to get the `/dev/tty` file from either of these? It is not intuitive to me from viewing either command's output

Comment: The output is descriptive, but not helpful for file system mounts. At least on Debian 11, it is not clear where the device is mounted, even though it shows all the bus information.

Answer (score 4):

This can show all USB devices, including devices that you don't have drivers.

```
system_profiler SPUSBDataType
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
lsblk -p -S -o  NAME,TRAN  | grep usb
```

Comment: This is good, but `lsblk -p -S` is sufficient, especially if you want to also check the vendor and and mode of the USB device.

Answer (score 0):

```
dmesg | grep ttyUSB | grep -v grep | grep -o ttyUSB[0-9]
```